# VPS server missing files

Tags: svn, files, repository

the strangest thing happend today. I was trying to acces the SVN repo but it gaved me an error, after looking into it i found that all the files are missing.

I had the following directory structure:
/coding/svn/reposotory/company/project1/
/coding/svn/reposotory/company/project2/
/coding/svn/reposotory/company2/project1/

And in project1, project2 there were the repos ...
Now i still have the folders ... but if i look in project1 for example its all empty.

I cant even imagine where they went. And its so strange that the directories are still there but the files are missing.

**CLARIFICATION**
I am not talking about the files under SVN control, but the actual repo files ( hooks, db, the whole dir )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered filesystem corruption?  A huge pile of missing files strongly suggests that sort of thing.  Check dmesg for partition or filesystem-related errors.

Comment: can you be more specific how you can do this ?

Comment: You're kidding, right?  Run the 'dmesg' command.

Answer (score 0):

Try `svn info`, check the output

```
Last Changed Rev: 1184
Last Changed Date: 2009-06-20 21:38:57 +1000 (Sat, 20 Jun 2009)
```

If the last change date is recent, it is likely that someone has made a mistake and `svn mv`ed  or overwritten then by accident.

Comment: there isnt any files in none of the repos ... so svn info would not help or even work

Comment: Please post the output of svn info $REPO

Comment: i dont think you understand ... in the folder project1 there used to be all the files for the repo ( DB, HOOKS, CONF etc ) now there are no files

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching both me and the server support we were unable to establich where the server files were gone.
We have given up looking, and assume that it was a very strange file-system error.

Answer (score -1):

(Note: this was posted before the question poster clarified that by "looking in [the repo]" he was not looking at the files stored in the repo, but at files outside the repo, those being the svn database files.)

`svn log -v file:///home/repo` on the root of the repo (change the URL as appropriate) will give you all of the changes to the repo, from most recent working backwards, listing the files that were added, deleted and modified. Using this, you can figure out if someone moved or deleted the files for which you're looking.

If that doesn't work, you have one of two problems:

1. You get a message along the lines of `Unable to open repository`, in which case you have the URL to your repository wrong. Find out where your repository is really located. It will have in it files and directories such as `README.txt`, `conf`, `db`, `format` and `hooks`.
2. Your URL is not for the root of your repo, but is within the repo (this will be the case if the version numbers in the log are not sequentially decreasing). Drop the last element from the end of the path in the URL and try again.

Comment: if u read more carefully you will see i am referring to the actual repo files not the ones under revision